# How to select last suggestion in google input tools

Tags: google-input-tools

I added google input tools extension to google chrome and it's working fine. Often I type documents in google docs with my native language and in there it contains some english words. As input tools give suggestions, english suggestion comes last. Is there a way to select the last suggestion quickly other than going one by one down using arrow keys or tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6th option in the list is the English suggestion. You can easily select it by typing 6 on your keyboard. Similarly, you can easily select any option in the list by typing the corresponding number.